# Linux c++ Convert seconds (double) to miliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, picoseconds

Tags: c++, linux

I have device which gives me delay in seconds (`char*`), value like `0.000003650000`, I have to convert that value to milliseconds, microseconds,  nanoseconds, or picoseconds.
I wrote an application, in qt-creator in linux (c++).
I tried to use library `chrono`, but as I see it is keeping only long values, for each type and I always loose some data. 
Which method is the best to do this?

Comment: provide the code you have written

Comment: Please show your code, as a [mcve]. As currently presented, this sounds awfully like a XY problem.

Comment: what kind of example do you want , I said I have char *value like
char *x = "0.000003650000" , which is time duration in seconds, how can I convert it to nanoseconds for example?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the `char*` to a `std::string`.  Check that there are exactly 12 digits after the decimal point.  Convert those to a `unsigned long long` number of picoseconds with `std::strtoull(digits,10);` (remember to specify the base explicitly, otherwise the leading zero will make it think it is an octal number).

If you need to handle delays >= 1s, convert the digits before the decimal point to a number of seconds in the same way and  add them into the picoseconds with `pico += seconds*(1000ull*1000*1000*1000);`

Finally, `nanoseconds = (picoseconds + 500)/1000;`

Comment: *"Finally, nanoseconds = (picoseconds + 500)/1000;"*

Why that (+500)? I cannot understand, thank you!

Comment: @BiagioFesta For mathematically correct integer rounding. Without the addition of half the divisor, the resulting integer value of lesser precision would be truncated and therefore rounded down instead of rounded up when the fractional part is >= .5.

Comment: @BiagioFesta: Sendaran has it exactly right.  If you want display nanoseconds *and* picoseconds, you'd write `nanoseconds = picoseconds / 1000; picoseconds %= 1000;`

Comment: @BiagioFesta: Sendaran has it exactly right.  If you want display nanoseconds *and* picoseconds, you'd write `nanoseconds = picoseconds / 1000; picoseconds %= 1000;`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could do this using `<chrono>` plus a few simple utilities found [here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using picoseconds = std::chrono::duration<long long, std::pico>;
using ldseconds = std::chrono::duration<long double>;

picoseconds
convert(const char* str)
{
    return date::round<picoseconds>(ldseconds{std::stold(std::string{str})});
}

int
main()
{
    auto t = convert("0.000003650000");
    using namespace date;
    std::cout << t << '\n';
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t) << '\n';
    std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(t) << '\n';
    std::cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t) << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
3650000ps
3650ns
3µs
0ms
```

**Detailed explanation**

First you need some custom `chrono::duration`s:

1. `picoseconds`, and
2. a `second` based on `long double`.

These are easily built as shown for the type aliases `picoseconds` and `ldseconds`.  The first template parameter is the representation you want to use.  The second is a `std::ratio` that represents a compile-time rational number that is the tick-period of your `duration`.  If you don't supply one (as in `ldseconds`), the default is `ratio<1, 1>`, which means seconds.

With these two custom durations, we can now easily write the `convert` function.  It should input the `const char*` (assumes null-terminated) and output the finest `duration` you anticipate (`picoseconds` in your example).

Use `std::stold` to convert a `std::string` holding the number into a `long double`.  Then convert that `long double` into `ldseconds`.  Finally convert the `ldseconds` into `picoseconds` using the chrono `round` utility found in [`"date/date.h"`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h):

`round` is also now in C++17. So if you have C++17, you can say `std::chrono::round` instead, which removes the need for [`"date/date.h"`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h) for this function.

Once the client gets the `picosecond` result, he can convert it to whatever units he wants with `duration_cast` (or in C++17, `round`, `floor`, or `ceil`).

I've used [`"date/date.h"`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h) just to make it easier to print the values out.  If you prefer, you can print them out without this utility like so:

```
std::cout << t.count() << "ps\n";
```